# Compare performance of multiple techniques statistically

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I have

- observations of the occurrence of the sea breeze at a coastal weather station by means of "Yes" and "No"
- 3 different techniques who all try to forecast the occurrence of the sea breeze wind at the same coastal weather station. The results are either "Yes" or "No".

How can I deduce by means of a statistical test if:

1. the results of the forecast technique are significantly different from the observations
2. which of the 3 techniques performs the best compared to observations?

Comment: The question seems to boil down to "Please tell me how to use and compare statistical classification methods."  I think it's far too broad for this website.

Comment: Section "3.2.1 Skill measures for point forecasts" of the document available at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/730c/f2bdc156b1ce8e63cd477ef071d668eb190d.pdf  will provide you with a good starting point.

Comment: Essentially, you can start by constructing a contingency table similar to Table 3 (pp. 45) in the document I suggested in my previous comment for each of your methods and use that table as a basis for computing various measures of forecast skills.  You can then compare those measures across merhods. Inference based on the tables will be complicated by the fact that you have temporal dependence.